# Placing GeoServer WMS layer within OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, openlayers

I have the following basic OpenLayers 3 code that opens a OSM background mapping and this works fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello PMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/ol3/css/ol.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/samples.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol-debug.js"></script>
        <script>            
            var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            });
            var uk_centre = ol.proj.transform([-2.547855, 54.00366], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            var view = new ol.View({
                center: uk_centre,
                zoom: 6
            });
            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map'
            });
            map.addLayer(osmLayer);
            map.setView(view);
            map.addControl(new ol.control.FullScreen());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am now looking to bring in a WMS layer from GeoServer with the code below, where would it be placed and what needs to be changed?

```
        var pms = new ol.layer.WMS("PMS",
        "http://10.0.1.127:8080/geoserver/PMS/wms",
        {layers: 'PMS:QGIS'} );
        map.addLayer(pms);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use code like I pasted below. Just change parameters. Look into [API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html)! ... Example is using geoserver's GWC module to show cached WMS in tiles (both dynamic/prerendered cache), for classic non cached WMS just delete "gwc/" from URL and change 'TILED' parameter to false.

Note1: To work with live data you have to turn off integration between WMS and WMTS in Geoserver settings (delete of "gwc/" isn't enought)

Note2: Don't get confused by CRS/SRS parameters. CRS is used for version 1.3.0 and SRS is used in older version.

```
var myLayer1303 = new ol.layer.Tile({
  extent: [2033814, 6414547, 2037302, 6420952],
  preload: Infinity,
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'WORKSPACE:LAYER', 'TILED': true, 'VERSION': '1.3.0',
      'FORMAT': 'image/png8', 'WIDTH': 256, 'HEIGHT': 256, 'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},
    serverType: 'geoserver'
    }))
  });
  map.addLayer(myLayer1303);
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidK, where would this tend to go within the code at the top?

Comment: Put this after map and view definition. Browse online examples.

Comment: can i pass  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms' thi surl dynamically from user defined form like link http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/map/bhuvan/bhuvan2d.php# in that tools tab--> Add Layer --> wms layer in that we just give our url and layer name only

Comment: like that i want to take url