# How to add a GeoServer WMS using OpenLayers-3?

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers

I am unable to figure out why I can't add WMS in OL3? Tiger is a default layer in Geoserver.

Below my code.

Open Street Map

```
</head>
```

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
 <div id="overlay" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 10px;">


<script>

        var wmsSource =new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS':'tiger:tiger_roads'},
        serverType:'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
        });

        var wmsLayer=new ol.layer.Image({
        source:wmsSource
        });

           var view = new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 1
            });

            var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [wmsLayer],
            target: 'map',
            view: view
            });
```

Comment: Hello, what error message are you getting?

Comment: try to change the url parameter to `url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',` to see if this solves the problem. Though you should get some kind of error within geoserver log

Comment: Even, when I change parameters : url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', it don't work . Here is link to this whole script: https://github.com/gisfan/wms

Comment: And I don't see a error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add labels to a WMS layer using OpenLayers and GeoServer?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/how-to-add-labels-to-a-wms-layer-using-openlayers-and-geoserver)

Comment: This was solved here already. You can check that solution - it is quite detailed http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139475/placing-geoserver-wms-layer-within-openlayers-3/139486#139486

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 var view = new ol.View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 1
        });
```

to

```
 var view = new ol.View({
        center: [-8208266.719431938, 4979872.392779233],
        zoom: 11
        });
```

Now you can see the WMS layer....

Comment: Please , could you tell me where I can find information about center  ?